# Django and Bootstrap modal ajax get data not working

Tags: ajax, django, modal-dialog

Good day everyone. I'm trying to implement bootstrap modal for the first time in Django 1.11.6 under python 3. I'm using postgresql too.

My Model

```
class DentalProcedures(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    proc_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    proc_tooth_no = models.CharField('Tooth No./s', max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    procedure = models.CharField('Procedure', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

My Modal Form

```
   <form id="procedureForm">
           {{form.as_p}}
           {% csrf_token %}
           <h2>{{ mypk }}</h2>
           <input type="hidden" name="patient" value="{{ mypk }}" id="id_patient">
           <div id="modalTreatment" class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <input id="saveProcedure" type="submit" value="Save"  class="btn btn-primary"  />
           </div>
       </form>
```

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#saveProcedure').click(function(e){
//  e.preventDefault();

             $.ajax({
                headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                type:"GET",
                url: "/",
                cache: false,
                data: {

                    tooth:  $('input[name="proc_tooth_no"]').val(),
                    date:  $('input[name="proc_date"]').val(),
                    proc:  $('input[name="procedure"]').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken').val()
                    },
                success : function(data) {

                    alert("congrats!");
                },
                  error: function(jqXHR, exception){
                    var msg = '';
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        msg = 'Parse error.';
                        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        msg = 'Time out error.';
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                    } else {
                        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                    }
                    $('#messages').html(msg);

                 }//end error
        });
    });
  });
```

My Views

```
class DentalProcedureCreateView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'patient/procedure_create.html'
    model = DentalProcedures
    fields = ['proc_tooth_no', 'proc_date', 'procedure']
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        fk = PatientInfo.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.patient = fk

        if self.request.is_ajax():

            tooth = self.request.GET.get('tooth')
            date = self.request.GET.get('date')
            procedures = self.request.GET.get('proc')

            proc = DentalProcedures()

            proc.proc_date = date
            proc.proc_tooth_no = tooth
            proc.patient = PatientInfo.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
            proc.procedure = procedures
            proc.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

My modal after submit displays the alert `"congrats"` but the data inside my form is failed to register in my db. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**: Attached is my terminal status when I added data in my form. It seems like there are two GET request happening. I can get the `/patient/list/view/1/?proc_date=2018-02-20` without modal by using `proc_date = self.request.GET.get('proc_date')` but I cannot get my `tooth` value in modal. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: post yourr view alsp

Comment: sorry I forgot the most important thing. I added it already.

Comment: have you tried to print the tooth inside the view to see if you are getting data in view or not?

Comment: I used `messages.success(self.request, tooth)` to print it but after submit, it stays on the same page and failed to display its value.

Comment: use the method post for the ajax, because i think GET is having some problem with the url matching. and do print(tooth) before proc = DentalProcedures() line and submit the form, and check if you get any print in the terminal

Comment: I tried to switch to POST method in ajax but it returned 405 status error.

Comment: did you get it .

Comment: put  pdb;pdb.set_trace() after self.request.is_ajax()  and check step by step what value you are getting

Comment: @Exprator I updated my question